# What is the purpose of webpack [hash] and [chunkhash]?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Could somebody tell me what is the the purpose [hash] and [chunkhash] and where do they come from?

```
output: {
    path: "/home/proj/cdn/assets/[hash]",
    publicPath: "http://cdn.example.com/assets/[hash]/"
}
```

Comment: yes, but it's still not clear what is it built for

Comment: hm...  [here](https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95#.oibt9ye3h) also quite interesting topic about it. Probably it will be quite easy to understand for you

Comment: @StepanSuvorov I'm sure you have figured it out meanwhile, but maybe my answer can help others understanding this.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This one wasn't obvious for me for a while, so I think it deserves some more detailed explanation.

**What the official documentation says:**

A brief description from the official [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames) about their purpose:

> A simple way to ensure the browser picks up changed files is by using
>   `output.filename` substitutions. The `[hash]` substitution can be used to
>   include a build-specific hash in the filename, however it's even
>   better to use the `[contenthash]` substitution which is the hash of the
>   content of a file, which is different for each asset.

Another explanation one by one from the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename) of `output.filename`:

- `[hash]` is a "unique hash generated for every build"
- `[chunkhash]` is "based on each chunks' content"
- `[contenthash]` is "generated for extracted content"

**Let's make it more more understandable with examples:**

I have 3 files in my `src` directory: `index.js`, `index.css`, `vendors.js`

Relevant parts from my example Webpack config:
(not a full, working config!)

```
entry: {
  index: ["./src/index.js", "./src/index.css"],
  vendors: ["./src/vendors.js"]
},
output: {
  filename: "[name].[hash].js"
}
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[hash].css"
  })
]
```

So I have 2 chunks name, `index` and `vendors`, but look that the `index` chunk will also have `css` content because it imports a `css` file in the array. When building, the `css` part will be exported to a separate file using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` (in my case) but Webpack knows that `index.js` and `index.css` belong to the same chunk.

Now let's try to build it with different hashing types. (changing the two `filename` option equally)

**Using [hash]:**

[image]

Every file has the same hash, because `[hash]` is generated based on all of our used source files. If I re-run the build without changing anything, the generated hash will remain the same. If I edit only one file then hash will change and all my generated bundles will have this new hash in their name.

**Using [chunkhash]:**

[image]

As you see, the 1st and 2nd files were coming from the same `index` chunk, so they have the same hash in their name. It's because `[chunkhash]` is generated based on the whole content of the given chunk. So if I edit let's say `index.css` and re-build, the files coming from the `index` chunk will have a new hash, but the one from `vendors` chunk will remain the same as was before.

**Using [contenthash]:**

[image]

This one is obvious. Each generated file has got a unique hash in their name, calculated from the content of that file. If I change let's say `index.css` an re-build, only the generated `index.css` will have a new hash.

Comment: Since I'm using hashes my users always get the updated version of the app, but the drawback is that unless Ctrl+F5 is pressed users might end up with console errors when the app is code-splitted and it's trying to dynamically pull a JS file with older version/hash (which is obviously not there anymore). Is there any best-practice workaround for that?

Comment: I believe best practice is to not empty your public folder before pushing new code and specifying `Cache-Control: no-cache` for your non-static files like `index.html`.

Comment: @szegheo You need to always burst caching for your main.js files. So whenever there's changes in any of the chunks you certainly need to add version control to the main js files. eg `main.js?v=new1.2`

Answer (score 11):

Basically its related to browser cacheing - when you serve assets you generally want to tell the client/browser that they can use the same script/stylesheet/jpeg etc without having to download it every single time. This is done by sending the appropriate HTTP header fields.

The problem then is how long should you tell the client they can keep using the same stylesheet for example? If you redesign your site and they dont download your new stylesheet they wont see those changes. The solution is usually to add some kind of identifier or version number to the stylesheet file name - if this id/version changes when the stylesheet changes (and thus the file name is different) the browser will download it again (this is known as cache busting).

Basically webpack can add a hash to the bundle output name that, being a function of the bundle content, will be different when the content changes - thus automating the process. `chunkhash` does the same thing if you are splitting a bundle into multiple chunks.

Heres some non-webpack related discussion: [Strategies for Cache-Busting CSS](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)