# Use Compilation Hash for asset/resource files in Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to use the compilation hash for asset/resource file names but no matter what I try it just generates a different hash for every file in the asset/resource output.  The chunk file names all get the same and correct compilation hash.

For example, the main bundle files are all correct:

appbundle.42cf6539b0e35868deab.js

polyfillsbundle.42cf6539b0e35868deab.js

etc..

However, the images in the assets folder look like this, with different hashes.  Is there a way to get them to match the compilation hash like the bundle chunks?

image1.ec620b3ff0d269c77f1b.svg

image2.984ca5bc273b4992cb6c.svg

etc..

Relevant webpack config:

```
output:
        {
            filename: '[name].[hash][ext]',
            chunkFilename: '[name].[hash][ext]',
            publicPath: './dist/',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[name].[hash][ext]'
        }
      ...

module: {
    rules: 
    [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
            type: 'asset/resource'
        },  
        ...             
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like both chunk file hashes are as same as with the asset ones. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

But what are you trying to achieve?

You are getting a new hash per image file, because with [`asset/resource`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) you asked Webpack to emit resources to separate files.
When you use [hash] placeholder, Webpack would generate a hash out of the filename. Since you have different filenames ~> different hashes.

If you want to add some random suffix per build to your resources, I'd do something like:

```
const seed = new Date().getTime() // or your generation strategy

module.exports = {
. . .
output:
        {
            . . .
            assetModuleFilename: `assets/[name].${seed}[ext]`
        }
      ...
```

Comment: I was under the assumption that [hash] was always a compilation hash that would change per build if something in the build was different.  And that in comprison, [contenhash] was based on the content of the file.  Why is the hash matching for bundle files as they are also "different" files?

Comment: I found a good answer to your last question from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176489/what-is-the-purpose-of-webpack-hash-and-chunkhash

Comment: I also tried to use Chunk-level substitution [chunkhash].
But Webpack did not replace that placeholder in assets filenames.
It seems that Webpack does not consider assets as a part of any chunk. 
I did not find a placeholder that could help you out of the box:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#template-strings