# How to ensure that after every new update in my react application in production, browser loads the data from server and not from cache?

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache, production-environment

I have seen various solutions for this approach, like adding a version number to my CSS file in index.html or adding a no-cache meta tag.
But all these solutions do not entirely fix the problem.
I want the browser to load from the cache when there is no update. But, if there is a new update, I want the browser to automatically load the fresh content from the server(that is, load the entire index.js file from the server) without the user having to reload the browser hard.

Also, my updates are sometimes not visible in the incognito mode. Why does this happen? As far as I know, there are no cache files in incognito Mode.

Comment: Most bundlers will allow you to add a hash to the files they emit. These hashes can usually be setup to be based on the build or the content of the emitted file. Since the file name then changes with each build or content update the browser will have to acquire it from the server as it will have no matching filename in the cache. There is a nice write up on this for webpack on a previous question someone else asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52786672/4364635